# "SELECT * from items where stock<=rol"; does not produce desired result in php

Tags: php, mysql

`"SELECT \* from items where stock\<=rol";`
The answer is not correct on the comparison value of stock and rol.
In case of a two digit number, it checks only the last digit for comparison process and results an undesired answer

I want to get correct answer as per the comparison stock<=rol.

Comment: Please don't tag spam. Apply only tags that are actually relevant to the question.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) sample data that is being selected and shouldn't and output of `show create table items;`

Comment: Can you try to run this in something that does not involve PHP (like MySQL Workbench, or MySQL shell), such that you can check whether PHP is relevant for this question?

Comment: SELECT * from items where stock<=rol; This ought to work. If not, verify that the stock and rol are of the int datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect that one or both of the columns in a datatype text, char, varchar etc. The comparison is then string and not numeric.
To force a numeric conversion we can multiply one of the values by 1.
Here I give an example of this problem.
The first query tests uses the int fields and we get the expected results. The second tests on the same values, but in VARCHAR fields and the result is not as we expect. In the third query we test using VARCHAR fields but we force a numeric comparison, which gives the required result.
NB `1` is true, `0` is false.

> ```
> SELECT 10 > 2 "numeric";
> SELECT '10' > '2' AS "string";
> SELECT 1 * '10' > '2' AS "forced numeric"
> ```
>
> ```
> | numeric |
> | ------: |
> |       1 |
>
> | string |
> | -----: |
> |      0 |
>
> | forced numeric |
> | -------------: |
> |              1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59e7456231f8cee3a0528e75500edcc8)*